# ES6 : 'this' is undefined in inherited class

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have two classes namely A and B respectively. The class definitions are as shown below.

```
class A {

    constructor(){
        ...
    }

    ...
}

//Implementation 1

class B extends A {
    constructor(){
        this.childProperty = "something"; // this is undefined.
    }
}

//Implementation 2

class B {
    constructor(){
        this.childProperty = "something"; // this is not undefined.
    }
}
```

Why is `this` undefined in `Implementation 1` and not in `Implementation 2`? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you creating an object `A` and an object `B`?  If you're doing `B()` and not `new B()`, that could explain the `this` issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to call `super()` first:

```
class B extends A {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.childProperty = "cool"
   }
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jb6qLzt/)

Comment: why do we need to call `super()`?

Comment: To make sure you inherit all properties/methods from your derived class. This is only necessary if you add a constructor yourself. Behind the scenes this will do something like `_super.call(this)`. [Use this typescript playground as a reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Y%20extends%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: is there a documentation that stated it is required for inherited class?

Comment: Yes, read through the documentation over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 5):

Try adding [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Super_class_calls_with_super) to your class:

```
class B extends A {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.childProperty = "something"; 
    }
}
```